# Regarding mandatory mark placement before or after field

Tags: formatting

This is regarding the mandatory mark placement on labels.
I am confused and want to know which is a right place to put a mandatory mark is it at the start of label or at the end?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Before field right after it's label gets more attention. But if your field does not have any label (e.g using placeholders in HTML) then it's place is after field.

I don't have enough reputation to comment. But this question is about placing mandatory mark after or before the actual field, not it's label. So @JonW you're wrong about duplication of this question.